# Cleanly kill all vim process from other tabs

Tags: linux, vim

I am using following Linux command to kill all vim process,

```
ps -ef | grep "gvim" | grep -v grep | awk '{print $2}' | xargs kill
```

Above command is working except it outputs:

```
Vim: Caught deadly signal TERM
```

Is there another clean way to kill it?

Comment: Do you need to be able to kill the Vim processes externally? Why not just switch to your gVim and do `:xa`?

Comment: nope. GUI is not option. I am using shell script to kill all vim process using above commands.

Comment: On linux, you'll be looking for `killall gvim` then.

Comment: @moopet That command by itself will still yield the same warning from Vim. Like `kill`, `killall` will by default send `SIGTERM`; this is what Vim is complaining about. So if OP were to go with the `killall` method, they would need to use `killall -9 gvim`, or something equally as murderous.

Comment: @Das_Geek I guess this depends on what you mean by "cleanly", then. To me, that means sending SIGTERM and allowing the process to tidy up. If you're just talking about hiding the warning, redirect it to `/dev/null`?

Comment: @moopet Yeah, `SIGTERM` is definitely nicer. Unfortunately Vim doesn't write unsaved changes, regardless of signal sent. But it would be much better for any background things a plugin might be doing.

Answer (score 2):

Well as long as you're fine with losing all unsaved changes and halting any background jobs mid-go, you can send a different signal from the `kill` command with the `-s` option. Signal `15`, `SIGTERM`, is the default one; you can do `kill -s 9` to **murder the processes outright**. Here is a good [list of signals](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/317496) for reference.

So your final command would look like:

```
ps -ef | grep "gvim" | grep -v grep | awk '{print $2}' | xargs kill -s 9
```

This does not generate any warnings about deadly signals. It's also a pretty nasty way of doing things, and could lead to some gnarly behavior if you've got a non-trivial vim setup.

As @moopet said in the comments, you can still use `SIGTERM` if you redirect the command's output to `/dev/null`. This won't be any nicer than `SIGKILL` in that Vim won't automatically save your files, but it may give any background tasks it was doing some time to clean up.

Alternatively, if you're willing to change your setup, you can always run a vim as a server and issue save-and-close commands to it from the terminal. There is a great explanation over on the [Vim SE site](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/13579/23686).

Answer (score 0):

I use this one to find and kill the VIM process.

```
ps axuw | grep vim | grep -v grep | awk '{print $2}' | xargs kill -9
```

Below is a breakdown of each step in the command above:

`ps axuw` # lists all processes on you PC.

`grep vim` # lists only processes that are running VIM.

`grep -v grep` # removes the processes that have "grep" in them, "-v" option shows the lines that do not match the specified pattern.

`awk '{print $2}'` # print the process id of the vim process(es) which is

second column. "*`awk`*" - allows to pass a command (eg: print). "*`$2`*" is the argument passed to print the 2nd column as it's, in fact, the second parameter in the result-set returned by the "*`print`*" command. In the "*`awk`*" you could also set a pattern to assure the command applies to only processes that follow it    (eg: `awk '/manager/ {print}' employee.txt` ; it would only print employees which title is the "manager" (not sure if it's looking for an exact match or just a keyword, though; feel free to test it).

`xargs kill -9` # kills the process; builds and executes commands provided through the standard input; "`-9`" is the index of the '*`kill`*' signal. To find signal numbers run `kill -l` command